# Is there any better way to get project type within netbeans platform application?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I am trying to create netbeans module which whould work upon standard maven  java projects. Is there  some better way to do that then how it was adviced in: [How can I get a project type on Netbeans Platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3023554/621742) This seems to be pretty dependent on implmenetation (note the *Impl postfix of the implementing class found in lookup). I couldn't find any standard method in the Project API. Any ideas? Or is it safe to rely on some "NbMavenProjectImpl" string?

Currently I am going this way:

```
Project mainProject = OpenProjects.getDefault().getMainProject();

if (mainProject == null) {
    return;
}
String projectType = mainProject.getClass().getName();
if (projectType.equals("NbMavenProjectImpl")) {
     // do some action with the project here
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be

```
if (mainProject.getLookup().lookup(NbMavenProject.class) != null) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Another one, which should be preferred, is to register your business logic into the maven project lookup eg. using an annotation

```
@ProjectServiceProvider(service=MyService.class, projectType="org-netbeans-modules-maven")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
  @Override
  public void doit() {
  }
}
```

and then accessing the business logic like

```
MyService ms = mainProject.getLookup().lookup(MyService.class);
if (ms != null) {
  ms.doit()
}
```

That way you can decouple your API from implementation and as a bonus you can share the same business logic between more project types, if appropriate.

Comment: Finally I had to use my solution mentioned above (it was for some work which couldn't wait). But thanks for your solutions as they are really clean and concise!